# Ubuntu-Rescue Remix Does Not See Hard Drive

Tags: linux, external-hard-drive, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to copy over data using the Ubuntu-Rescue Remix bootable cd but this cd does not see my hard drive!  What can I do so that the URR is able to see my hard drive and I can save my data?

I tried the `lshw` Linux command and this is the one not showing my drive.

EDIT......
One hard drive completely died (I believe it lost the mbr), I tried using testdisk to recover and it could not recover.  So I have the bad drive & a "new" drive connected via USB to a computer booting into URR to attempt to copy the image over to the "new" drive.  But URR is not showing the "new" drive...

EDIT # 2
`'sudo fdisk -l'`will show my drive as `dev/sdb` and the partition is listed as `/dev/sdb1`

EDIT # 3
Using `sudo ddrescue image /dev/sdb` gives me an error of:

> Output file exists and is not a regular file.  Use --force if you really want to overwrite it, but be aware that all existing data in output file will be lost.

****Not sure if it makes a difference I am copying from a Linux format to a NTFS format..could that be what throws the error?  If so, how do I format the final drive to a format that can be seen?

Comment: why exactly are you trying to use URR? is your hard disk displaying instability or did your existing system just stop booting?

Comment: One hard drive completely died (I believe it lost the mbr), I tried using testdisk to recover and it could not recover.  So I have the bad drive & a "new" drive connected via USB to a computer booting into URR to attempt to copy the image over to the "new" drive.  But URR is not showing the "new" drive...

Comment: check your connections and reboot. while you are booting, see if the system bios sees the drive. if the bios can't see it, the OS has no chance. if the bios shows it, boot up with urr and try `sudo fdisk -l`. does it show the drive? Did you format the drive? if not use gparted to put a partition and filesystem on it. then check again to see if urr can detect and mount the filesystem.

Comment: @FrankThomas using your suggested 'sudo fdisk -l' the drive is shown it is '/dev/sdb' & '/dev/sdb1' .... BIOS also can see this drive, just not when rin 'lshw'

Comment: try mounting the volume then. assuming it is a linux native filesystem type try 'sudo mkdir \media\new; sudo mount \dev\sdb1 \media\new'.

Comment: that got it seeing the drive...now when I try 'sudo ddrescue image /dev/sdb' I get an error, see my edit.

Comment: is your image of the disk or the partition?

Comment: I think the disk...This is the command I used to make it 'sudo ddrescue -r 3 /dev/sdb image log'

Comment: well, in that case, you need to overwrite the drive, not the partition, so we need to unmount the disk. `sudo umount /dev/sdb1`. then try your command again. as long as sdb is not null, the drive should be available for this kind of operation. you will be overwriting the entire disk, including any MBR, bootsectors, partition tables, partitions, filesystems ...Everything. your drive will cease to be NTFS if everything works as expected.